# Select rolling date range from year/month instead of date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to select the last 12 months of rolling demand from a table that contains the following fields:

```
Item,
Year,
Month,
Demand Qty
```

I have tried the following:

```
Select Item, [Year], [Month],[Demand QTY]
FROM [table1]
Where   
(
    [Year] >= Year(getdate())-'1'
and [Month] >= Month(getdate())
)
and
(
    [Year] < year(getdate())+'1'
and [Month] <= month(getdate())
)
```

but I am only getting the records for last year and this year of the current month.

```
Item    Year    Month   Demand Qty
CD051   2011    3       8800
CD051   2012    3       0
```

I'm still a rookie so I could be making obvious mistakes. Could someone please help me?

Comment: We need to see some more of your data (a few records that you think should be selected, but aren't being). Also, why are you adding and subtracting a string from Year()?

Comment: If possible, change your table's structure and store the years/months as `date` or `datetime` values, then derive `Year` and `Month` only in your queries or as static [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx "Computed Columns (SQL Server)"). That way it'll be easier for you to filter rows based on the given date, and the queries would likely be more optimisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Select Item, [Year], [Month],[Demand QTY] 
FROM [table1] 
Where ( [Year] = Year(getdate())-'1' and [Month] >= Month(getdate()) ) or 
      ( [Year] = year(getdate()) and [Month] <= month(getdate()) )
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I assumed it would be simple enough to get the average of the demand by adding "AVG([Demand QTY]) as AvDem" and a Group By to the query, its not working though. Any tips?

Comment: @Flashgordan: In what way is it not working (does it return an error, no results, the wrong results etc) and what grouping did you use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this:

```
Select * from TableName where (([Year] * 100) + [Month]) >= ((Year(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate())) * 100) + (Month(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate()))))
```

This will only give you between 12 months ago and today

```
Select * from TableName where (([Year] * 100) + [Month]) between ((Year(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate())) * 100) + (Month(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate())))) and (Year(GetDate()) * 100 + Month(GetDate()))
```

For an average, you should be able to add

```
Select [Year], [Month], Avg([Demand QTY]) AvgDemand from TableName where (([Year] * 100) + [Month]) between ((Year(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate())) * 100) + (Month(DateAdd(mm, -12, GetDate())))) and (Year(GetDate()) * 100 + Month(GetDate()))
Group by [Year], [Month]
```

Just remember that if you have other columns in your query that would make the row unique, you Avg wont give you what you expect

Comment: This works well for the start date, but it includes all data in the future as well. I am only looking for the last 12 months data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you wanted to limit it to only today, I've changed my answer